How to highlight text in Slack like I can in Microsoft Teams chat
In Microsoft Teams Chat, I can highlight selected text with a color on the text background or change color of the font.
I can't find a way to do that in Slack.

Which Slack interface are you using? Are you talking about formatting the text of messages you send?

No. Not the usual markdown formatting.  I think the problem with Slack is it uses markdown not HTML in chat messages.

As of today, it's not possible to color or highlight text within messages in Slack.
Related reading:

Author of Markdown about HTML and formatting


The idea for Markdown is to make it easy to read, write, and edit prose. HTML is a publishing format; Markdown is a writing format. Thus, Markdown’s formatting syntax only addresses issues that can be conveyed in plain text.


Formatting options in Slack


While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
